# How do I make Heroku recongise Procfile on the app/website?

Tags: heroku

Okay after many issues with `Heroku`, I have narrowed it down to it not reconsigning my `Procfile`, when I go onto my account and run `bash` then `ls` this comes up: I'm running lastest `Groovy Gorilla` and `Python 3.9`.

```
directory      index.php         Me         requirements.txt
composer.json  myapp             Project    runtime.txt
db.sqlite3     manage.py         projects   venv
```

Then I ran  `heroku ps`
this came up:

```
 Warning: heroku update available from 7.56.0 to 7.56.1.
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 548h 30m (99%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 1h 29m (0%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

No dynos on myapp
```

Here's my `Procfile:` on `Pycharm`-name `Procfile`

```
  web: gunicorn.Project.wsgi
```

Its connected to `github` and possibly `CLI`

```
The requirements.txt:

asgiref==3.4.1
boto3==1.18.5
botocore==1.21.5
certifi==2021.5.30
charset-normalizer==2.0.3
click==8.0.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2.5
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.2
Pillow==8.3.0
psycopg2==2.9.1
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.26.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
urllib3==1.26.6
whitenoise==5.3.0
```

How do I make it recongise `Procfile?` I'm really don't know what to do.

Comment: ask ubuntu is a Q&A site. What is your question? Please read [ask] then [edit] accordingly

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I discovered that adding `-b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 10` to my `myapp/Procfile` worked:
Now so I added this on `Pycharm:`

```
web: gunicorn.Project.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 10
```

On the website it comes up as:
web `gunicorn.Portfolio.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 10` -there is no `:` on the website.